# Git: How to create a tag that also include submodules?

Tags: git, tags

I got a project with many submodules, I just made a release and I want to tag it all.

I want to create a point where I can checkout in the future and it will include the current code of my project along with all the current code of all submodules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tag a commit, you *are* tagging the version of your submodules that is being used by that commit.

When you use a submodule, your commit includes the SHA of the commit in the submodule that your code is currently using. When you update the code in your submodule, you will see that you have changes to commit (the new SHA) in the super project. So, a tag will naturally work the way you want.

Comment: Agree. You can see that in your project it just links to your sobmodule's commits. It's like: ```Subproject commit 0334f3c9f940179c11f793a2dd26f051f095b521```