# Any way to tag multiple repos at once with Android Studio?

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have several git repos for my project, and it works ok, I can commit, push, branch just fine, but I would like to be able to tag all of them at the same time. Is that possible with Android Studio?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is [setting up a multi-rooted project](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/08/git-branches-for-multi-root-projects/), but there does not seem to be an option (`Version Control | Git`) to execute *tag* operations on all roots.

Another option would be to have one parent repository with all your working repos as [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules): Android Studio would only work with them as you do currently, but the [parent repo can be used to tag all submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320966/6309) (from command-line though)

So:

- keep your current setup unchanged
- have a separate clone of a parent repo referencing your projects as submodule: [you can refresh them in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/6309), and tag them from that separate directory structure whenever you need to make a release.

Comment: I already have all my repos on Android Studio and manage them as having `common branches` and that works great, I can branch all at once or switch branches or delete branches on all of them at the same time, I just need a way to tag them. The submodules seems like an interesting way of doing it but I would have to change my file system structure, not too terrible. Are there maybe external tools I can use to do this? I only need to do it when I tag releases or important stuff.

Comment: @casolorz "I can use to do this? I only need to do it when I tag releases or important stuff": then you can have a separate tree folder, dedicated to your parent repo and its subfolders (your projects repos), that you would refresh (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1032653/6309), and from which you can tag them all in one go. The rest of the time, you could be working in your current setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple repos using Preferences > Version Control > Directory Mappings, click on "+" and select directory and VCS as Git (or the version control that you use)
[image]

Comment: Already doing that but there isn't an option to create a tag on all repos at once.